# How to loop through this dictionary

Tags: c#

I have declared a dictionary like this:

```
Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<string, string>> dc = new Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
```

now how can I loop through it? I wanted something like the following so I created that dictionary:

name1
oldValue1
newValue1

name2
oldValue2
newValue2

...

Comment: I would use a [`Tuple`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd387181.aspx) instead of a `KeyValuePair`. But that's just me.

Comment: Can you explain what this dictionary is for? It is a somewhat strange thing to do to map a key to a key-value pair. There might be a better data structure to do what you want. Are the "old" and "new" values actually keys and values? It doesn't sound like the old value is a key; it sounds like it is a value.

Comment: @EricLippert It seems like he's using `KeyValuePair` to store an old value of something in the key and the new value in value.

Comment: If you are using C# 4.0, you should use `Tuple<string, string>` instead of `KeyValuePair<>` (unless clearly you are recycling the KeyValuePair of another dictionary)

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ : yes, you are correct about storing old value and new value.

Comment: @xanatos: yes Tuples are a nicer choice but my other team members are still on VS 2008 and I think that one is .NET 3.5 so cannot use Tuple.

Comment: @EricLippert: Eric like xantos mentioned I am  using KeyValuePair to store an old value of something in the key and the new value in value. I could use Tuples but well it is for .NET 4.0 and my other team members are still on VS2008

Comment: @BDotA You are right... And I did the same more times I want to remember :-)

Comment: This seems dangerous and error prone, to put a value in a field called "Key". Structs are cheap; why don't you just make a `struct Replacement<T> { public T OldValue { get; private set; } public T NewValue { get; private set; } ...` and use that? I once spent several hours debugging code where some bozo had decided to store left, top, width and height of a rectangle in a struct with fields named left, top, right, bottom because he was too lazy to define a struct with the correct names. It was extremely difficult to debug because half the names were wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can loop through it like so

```
foreach (var pair in dc)
{
    string name = pair.Key;
    string oldValue = pair.Value.Key;
    string newValue = pair.Value.Value;

    // use the values 
}
```

But I have a feeling you're using the wrong tool for the job. It sounds to me like you really need to go ahead and define a proper class to hold the names and values, and then just work with a `List<T>` of that class.

Comment: Nice! you are right also about using the class instead of a dictionary, that way my previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615640/what-is-a-good-structure-to-save-this-data/7616037#7616037

Comment: You can probably use the Tuple<> class, instead of creating your own (if you're lazy like me :))

Comment: @SaguiItay: yes Tuple was a better choice but it is only on .NET 4.0 and other team members still have VS2008 installed.

Comment: @Saguiltay, the problem with `Tuple<>` is similar to the problem with the `Dictionary` approach. If you're using it inside a method as an implementation detail and nobody ever has to see it, maybe you go ahead and use it. If you start passing it around for use by other methods, it's definitely time to give it the class treatment, so that it can self-document what it contains. `tuple.Item1` and `tuple.Item2` tells me nothing. `theClass.Name` and `theClass.SomeValue` tells me quite a lot.

Comment: Even if not passing it around, a class is often justified, as it provides documentation for the poor maintenance programmer that comes back to the code 6 months later and has no idea what the author intended with the `.Item1` and `.Item2` or the `.Key`, `.Value.Key`, `.Value.Value`. Don't be hesitant to use classes, even for the "trivial" things.

Answer (score 5):

```
foreach( KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in  dc )
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}",  kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
}
```

When you loop a dictionary you use KeyValuePair that is generic. Since your dictionary contain the key as string and the value as string, this one will take also a string for both.

You can access the key with `kvp.Key` and the value with `kvp.Value`.

For your example, you are using a Dictionary of string that contain a value of KeyValuePair.
So, you can have the exact print you want with :

```
foreach( KeyValuePair<string, KeyValuePair<string,string>> kvp in  dc )
{
    Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key + " " + kvp.Value.Key + " "+ kvp.Value.Value);
}
```

Comment: Good only if you put dc.Values

Comment: His dictionary's value is not a `string` it's a `KeyValuePair<string, string>`.

Comment: You know, it's still wrong. The second part should be KeyValuePair<string, KeyValuePair<string, string>>